# UNION ALL taking days. Speeding up?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I've got two tables: one is about 200 million rows, the other about 100 million.  I need to join them together and select about 3/4 of their rows and 1/6 of their columns, so have created a new table, and am inserting into it using:

```
INSERT INTO NEWTABLE 
SELECT COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3, COLUMN4
FROM TABLE1
UNION ALL 
SELECT COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3, COLUMN4
FROM TABLE2 
LOCK IN SHARE MODE;
```

This is taking a while.  Days in fact.

Am I doing this the fastest way?

My *feeling* is that the query is not the main issue - it's the copying of both source tables to a temporary table that takes the time.  How do I prove this?  And if that's the case, can I circumvent it?

Thank you!

Comment: Can't you just insert them separately?

Comment: Can you give us an exact time?

Comment: What does the execution plan say

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why union all?

```
INSERT INTO NEWTABLE
SELECT COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3, COLUMN4
FROM TABLE1
LOCK IN SHARE MODE;

INSERT INTO NEWTABLE
SELECT COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3, COLUMN4
FROM TABLE2 
LOCK IN SHARE MODE;
```

achieves the same.

Comment: Would that be faster? And stupid question (sorry, I'm learning) - if that's faster, what's the point of a union?

Comment: @DazedandConfused, well, you can select without inserting, sometimes you might want to unify two result sets in one query. I'd suggest that in your case, the limiting perforamnce factor is growing the index on `NEWTABLE`, so this may not help as much as you might hope.

Comment: @DazedandConfused if you are creating the new table soley for the purpose of aggregating the results, you'd benefit from applying the conditions earlier. That way you'll have to work with just a quarter of the data and you'll benefit from any indexes on the base tables.

Comment: Thank you very mcuh for your help.  'you'd benefit from applying the conditions earlier' - can you explain?  The tables I am aggregating from I only have read access to.  Are you proposing an intermediate step?

Comment: @DazedandConfused at some point you want to select a 1/4 of the data, as you say in the question. The sooner you do that, the less data the engine will have to churn. Effectively, add your `WHERE` clauses to your subqueries. If you have enough memory you may find its quicker to avoid `NEWTABLE` and continue with `UNION ALL`

Comment: Oops - I meant 3/4 of the rows (not 1/4 as I wrote), but I think your point still stands.  Does the fact I'm not selecting all the columns have an effect?

Comment: @DazedandConfused the number of columns will have an impact, more or less but, the scale of the effect depends on the execution plan of the query. The plan will vary based on your schema, indexes, resources etc...

Answer (score 0):

Removing UNION ALL is enough. Despite, if you are having problems, kindly post time difference here.

- Disable indexes on NEWTABLE if it is having
- Run two INSERT DDLs.
- Enable indexing